Nextjs 14 right way call server actions on server components
I'm using nextjs 14 with server side actions.
My issue is that everytime that I try to set new params it takes a lot to update them.
I guess this is because the whole route is refreshed so the server action(s) are called again, so it makes the page to not feel smoth cause the request is being executed again and again.
import EstadoDeCuentaGrid from "@/portalModules/estadoDeCuenta/EstadoDeCuentaGrid";
import { Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
...

const EstadoDeCuenta = async () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Heading>Estado de cuenta</Heading>

      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <EstadoDeCuentaGrid />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

export default EstadoDeCuenta;


import { getStudentWithTransactions } from "@/lib/actions";
import DebtSummary from "@/portalModules/estadoDeCuenta/DebtSummary";
import PaymentsModule from "@/portalModules/estadoDeCuenta/PaymentsModule";
import TransactionsHistory from "@/portalModules/estadoDeCuenta/TransactionsHistory";
import { Flex, Grid, GridItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const EstadoDeCuentaGrid = async () => {
  const loggedUserTransactions = await getStudentWithTransactions(); // The issue might be right here
  console.log("Action being called");
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Grid
        h="90vh"
        sx={{
          maxWidth: { base: "100vw", md: "100%" },
          width: { base: "100vw", md: "100%" },
        }}
        templateRows={{ base: "repeat(3, 1fr)", md: "repeat(2, 1fr)" }}
        templateColumns={{ base: "repeat(1, 1fr)", md: "repeat(2, 1fr)" }}
        gap={4}
        boxSizing="border-box"
      >
        <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, md: 1 }} rounded="md">
          <DebtSummary loggedUserTransactions={loggedUserTransactions} />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, md: 1 }} rounded="md">
          <PaymentsModule loggedUserTransactions={loggedUserTransactions} />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, md: 2 }} rounded="md">
          <TransactionsHistory
            loggedUserTransactions={loggedUserTransactions}
          />
        </GridItem>
      </Grid>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default EstadoDeCuentaGrid;

So inside my Debt summary component I update the url params using
    params.set("schoolGradeGroupId", selectedSchoolGradeGroup.id.toString());
    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);

I am sure that the issue is that
const loggedUserTransactions = await getStudentWithTransactions();

is being called every time I update the url params, cause if I delete that code, the page runs smooth, no issues at all.
So what am I doing wrong here?
Note: I am calling a prisma code that ask for data to supabase database.
